# String to PublicKey Header is too long

Tags: java, string, security, header, base64

I'm trying to create public key from string in this way:

```
byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(publicKeyStr.getBytes("utf-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
```

but

```
keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
```

causes error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
```

Any other solutions and examples of creating PublicKey form String ?

The String is:

> 87Avu4YRFh25mG/5/vW7tFXORD3WYqByKZDHpcqstXKDyLYFtm8arbwXDUxcDRSJUKdZx07L1fGvExfslShssJ22nHA4bScQ7yhgrtsxNUa5NPPP/YlR9DLAnjFzf3AEbW26fLO5luQtDIDmjSvwNE6ZwAIjhRJ3HXpqw2hFMvc=AQAB

Comment: Are you sure that UTF-8 is the correct charset in which to get the bytes?

Comment: yes, i'm sure it's UTF-8

Comment: Maybe importat is that this string is "modulus" ?

Comment: Ciphertext and keys should both consist of random bytes. Neither one of them can be represented 1:1 with a string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867840/java-security-spec-invalidkeyspecexception-and-inappropriate-key-specification-e

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution here [RSA. Java Encryption .NET Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148072/rsa-java-encryption-net-decryption)

The problem was that my string was Modulus + Exponential in one string.
When i split it to two diferent Strings and generate like there. The key was generated successfuly. Also there was a problem with encoding UTF-16LE.